# Freeform Pro date_range_end

Tags: solspace-freeform

EEEnthusiasts!

I have a client who is seeking to use Freeform Pro to create a form where site visitors can submit entries that will appear on another part of the site for 10 days from the date of submission, and then expire automatically. It seems like the Freeform Pro **[date_range_end](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/#date_range_end)** parameter should be able to do this (or at least the client thinks so), but the following template code is not working as expected.

```
{exp:freeform:entries
form_id="9|11"
orderby="entry_date"
sort="desc"
status="open"
date_range_end="10 day"
}
```

Does the **date_range_end** parameter not actually do what we thought it would? Is it being used incorrectly here? Is there a better way of achieving the same effect?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!